# Modelica: initial condition for step function

Tags: modelica, dymola, openmodelica

I would like to ask a Modelica question about when function, and the following source code cannot be properly functioned.  The variable Pstart_CONV is an initial condition for der(x_calc) in the if statement, and the Pstart_CONV value is given by x when the "when statement" becomes true.  Because x is a step function, I want to assign an initial condition for der(x_calc) so x can be continued for the whole domain.

Thank you very much,

Source:

```
model Unnamed4
  Real  Pstart_CONV;

  Real P_crit_ratio;
  parameter Real P_crit_ratio_criteria = 2.00;

  Real x;
  Real x_calc(start=0);

equation 
  P_crit_ratio = 10-time;

  when P_crit_ratio <= P_crit_ratio_criteria then
    Pstart_CONV = x;
  end when;

  if P_crit_ratio >= P_crit_ratio_criteria then
    x = time^2;
    x_calc = 0;
  else
    der(x_calc) = time * 5;
    x = x_calc + Pstart_CONV;
  end if;   
end Unnamed4;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues I see with this code.  The main one has to do with the fact that this is what is called a "variable index" problem.  I'll address that.  But first, I want to point out that your `if` and `when` clauses are not properly synchronized.  What I mean by that is that the change in behavior represented by your `if` statement will not necessarily occur at the same instant that the `when` clause is activated.

To address this, you can easily refactor your model to look like this:

```
model Model1
  Real Pstart_CONV;
  Real P_crit_ratio;
  parameter Real P_crit_ratio_criteria=2.00;
  Real x;
  Real x_calc(start=0);
  Boolean trigger(start=false);
equation 
  P_crit_ratio = 10-time;

  when P_crit_ratio <= P_crit_ratio_criteria then
    Pstart_CONV = x;
    trigger = true;
  end when;

  if trigger then
    der(x_calc) = time * 5;
    x = x_calc + Pstart_CONV;
  else
    x_calc = 0;
    x = time^2;
  end if;
end Model1;
```

Now, both the `if` and `when` clauses are tied to the `trigger` variable.  Now we can address your main problem which is that on one side of your `if` statement you have:

```
der(x_calc) = time * 5;
```

...and on the other side you have:

```
x_calc = 0;
```

In practice, what this means is that for part of the simulation you solve `x_calc` using a differential equation while during the other part of the simulation you solve `x_calc` using an algebraic equation.  This leads to the "variable index" problem because the "index" of the DAE changes depending on whether the value of `trigger` is true or false.

One approach to this is to modify the equations slightly.  Instead of using the equation `x_calc = 0` we specify an initial condition of `0` for `x_calc` and then enforce a differential equation that says the value of `x_calc` doesn't change, *i.e.,* `der(x_calc) = 0`.  In other words, get the same behavior by removing an algebraic equation settings `x_calc` to a constant and replacing it with an equation where we set the initial value of `x_calc` to be the desired value and then add a differential equation that, in effect, simply says the value of `x_calc` doesn't change.

Making such a change in your case leads to the following model:

```
model Model2
  Real Pstart_CONV;
  Real P_crit_ratio;
  parameter Real P_crit_ratio_criteria=2.0;
  Real x;
  Real x_calc(start=0);
  Boolean trigger(start=false);
initial equation
  x_calc = 0;
equation
  P_crit_ratio = 10-time;

  when P_crit_ratio <= P_crit_ratio_criteria then
    Pstart_CONV = x;
    trigger = true;
  end when;

  if trigger then
    der(x_calc) = time * 5;
    x = x_calc + Pstart_CONV;
  else
    der(x_calc) = 0;
    x = time^2;
  end if;
end Model2;
```

I tested it, and this model ran using SystemModeler (although I don't know enough about your problem or the expected results to truly validate the results).

I hope that helps.

Comment: If this answers your question, please mark it as an answer (click the check mark next to the answer).

Comment: OK, sorry this is my first time to use this platform.  Thanks a lot!